# Is there a method to debug a cycle issue with Terraform

Tags: terraform

I met a complicated issue with Terraform, with an error like this :

```
module.sbox_stack_resources.data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.datadog_api_key (expand), 
module.sbox_stack_resources.random_string.akhqpwd["dev-01"] (destroy), module.sbox_stack_resources.random_string.akhqpwd["dev-01"], 
module.sbox_stack_resources.module.datadog_monitor["a-sbox-jxc5-pg1"].datadog_monitor.monitor["[cpe][sandbox] - sbox-jxc5 Disk Used pg1"] (destroy), 
module.sbox_stack_resources.random_string.akhqpwd["dev-02"] (destroy), 
module.sbox_stack_resources.module.datadog_monitor["a-sbox-jxc5-pg1"].datadog_monitor.monitor["[cpe][sandbox] - sbox-jxc5 CPU Used pg1"] (destroy), 
module.sbox_stack_resources.module.datadog_monitor["a-sbox-jxc5-pg1"].datadog_monitor.monitor["[cpe][sandbox] - sbox-jxc5 Deadlock pg1"] (destroy), 
module.sbox_stack_resources.random_string.akhqpwd["dev-02"], 
module.sbox_stack_resources.local.gke_components (expand), 
module.sbox_stack_resources.local.global_datadog_disabled (expand), 
module.sbox_stack_resources.data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.datadog_app_key (expand), 
module.sbox_stack_resources.provider["registry.terraform.io/datadog/datadog"], 
module.sbox_stack_resources.module.datadog_monitor["a-sbox-jxc5-pg1"].datadog_monitor.monitor["[cpe][sandbox] - sbox-jxc5 Connection pg1"] (destroy)
```

It occurred during a `terraform apply`.

I won't post the Terraform code, because there is too much-implicated code, and it's not the purpose of my question.

My question is : is there a way to have more information about the cycle issue? I try to enable `TF_LOG=debug`, but I'm drowning in logs.

I try to create a small project with only implicated resources, and try to met the same state, but every terraform apply runs well.

So is there a way to get more information about this `cycle` error ?